# Getting Setting build path error when trying to change the

Tags: java, eclipse, websphere, clearcase, ibm-rad

I'm getting a *'Setting build path' has encountered a problem.  File is read only* error when I try to select WebSphere Application Server v6.1 in my Java Build Path in Enterprise Explorer in Rational Application Developer:

[image]

Details just says "File is read only."  Does anyone know what file it's talking about?

I ran SysInternals Process Explorer filtering for the result "ACCESS DENIED" and I didn't see anything.  If I create a read-only text file file and attempt to modify it, it pops up in the list in SysInternals Process Explorer.

Comment: Are you using snapshot or dynamic view? Is that WebSphare Application server part of your ClearCase view?

Answer (score 1):

Check first if files likely to be changed as a result of your "Java Build Path" selection are checked out.

Typically, if the `.classpath` is *not* checkout, your selection would not be able to proceed, and that kind of error message would be seen ("`File is read only`").

The line change (in `.classpath`, as seen [in this thread](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=90b8c36c-905c-475e-a7a1-244fe53fb5ab)) would be from:

```
 <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jst.server.core.container/com.ibm.ws.ast.st.runtime.runtimeTarget.v61/was.base.v61">
```

to:

```
 <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jst.server.core.container/com.ibm.ws.ast.st.runtime.runtimeTarget.v61/WebSphere Application Server v6.1">
```